# how to compare two cells with strings in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, compare, analysis

I have a pandas dataframe as follows:

> **FIRST GOAL          WINNER**
>
> Algeria                   brazil 
>  
>   Argentina            Argentina 
>   Japan              Germany  
>   brazil             brazil 
>   france                    France

i want to check if the first goal scorer is the winner of the game. can some one help?

Comment: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  """Entry point for launching an IPython kernel.

I got this error. can you please help? Thank you

Comment: Pss: consider accepting answer, if it helped.

Answer (score 6):

You need:

```
df['is_winnder'] = df['FIRST GOAL'].str.lower() == df['WINNER'].str.lower()
```

Output:

```
    FIRST GOAL  WINNER   is_winnder
0    Algeria     brazil       False
1  Argentina  Argentina        True
2      Japan    Germany       False
3     brazil     brazil        True
4     france     France        True
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC:
You need to compare `france` to `France` which requires normalization of the string.  We can make all letters `UPPER`, `lower`, or `Title`.  I went with `lower`.

### `nunique`

Stack, then use `str.lower` to normalize capitalization.
In this answer, I stacked the dataframe in order to only have to call `str.lower` once on the stacked Series object.  I then determined the number of unique values per the first level of the index, which were our old rows. If the number of unique values is equal to one, then the columns must have been equal.

```
df.stack().str.lower().groupby(level=0).nunique().eq(1)

0    False
1     True
2    False
3     True
4     True
dtype: bool
```

Or

```
df.assign(is_winner=df.stack().str.lower().groupby(level=0).nunique().eq(1))

  FIRST GOAL     WINNER  is_winner
0    Algeria     brazil      False
1  Argentina  Argentina       True
2      Japan    Germany      False
3     brazil     brazil       True
4     france     France       True
```

---

### `Series.str.lower`

This is virtually identical to Harv Ipan's answer with the exception that I added `str.lower()`.

```
df.assign(is_winner=df['FIRST GOAL'].str.lower() == df['WINNER'].str.lower())
```

---

### `applymap`

This is succinct.  One call using `applymap` that uses `str.lower`.  Then I got tricky with unpacking the `values` array into an `eq` operator.

```
from operator import eq

df.assign(winner=eq(*df.applymap(str.lower).values.T))
```

Comment: very clever use of `applymap` bravo